# Spring Data without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-data-jpa

I want to use SpringData (JPA I guess to access Postgres) with my Spring / GWT project. I cannot use SpringBoot because it does not allow me to register a simple HttpServlet (the GWT RemoteServiceServlet). At least, I can't figure that out due to too much magic and poor documentation.

Can anyone point me at a sample Maven project that uses SpringData *without* SpringBoot?

Comment: My answer had both spring boot and spring reference in the maven projects, better it be a comment for you to decide if it helps you . [Spring Data Examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples) , [Spring Data - Release Train BOM example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/bom) , [Official Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#preface)

Comment: Looks like every example there derives from Spring Boot so that's no good. I just want good old plain Spring.

Comment: you are not [alone](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/305) :) and a similar [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556217/4214241) with xml based config

Comment: The best place now to ask for GWT questions is to join https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt