# Spring data JPA WITHOUT an entire Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating an internal CLI that is communicating with a PostgreSQL database and the easiness to create a no-code repository is one of the features that convince me to choose Spring data JPA.

However, I am not able to find some tutorial or GitHub repository to set up a Spring data JPA project without an entire spring boot application.

On the project https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-book/tree/master/jpa there is no main entry point, so the code is not runnable and by the way, it was updated 8 years ago ...

This other StackOverflow thread [Spring Data JPA without Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974249/spring-data-jpa-without-spring-boot) does not help me because the guy could run his spring application on Google Cloud Platform finally (that was the cause of why he ask how to setup sping data jpa without spring boot).

I don't know how to start, if you have any ideas I will be happy to discuss with someone who is more experienced than me.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the abbreviation "gcp" stands for?

Comment: @Nikolas Google Cloud Platform :)

Comment: I've edited your question to be clearer for these who are not familiar with it :)

Comment: Great but GCP has no connection with the subject of my question, it was just for informational purposes, so I removed the tag google cloud platform that you've set.

Comment: And why not a Spring Boot application? You can use that perfectly fine as a CLI application? Just don't include the web stuff and you have a CLI application. Else just write a regular Spring application, include Spring Data JPA and configure as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This might help if no more complete tutorial turns up https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Look for this section

> Standalone usage

> You can also use the repository infrastructure outside of a Spring container, e.g. in CDI environments. You still need some Spring libraries in your classpath, but generally you can set up repositories programmatically as well. The Spring Data modules that provide repository support ship a persistence technology-specific RepositoryFactory that you can use as follows

In particular it says you can use a factory to generate repositories:

```
RepositoryFactorySupport factory = … // Instantiate factory here
UserRepository repository = factory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
```

So adding the spring parts that contain the spring data classes may be enough for this level and if you want to have DI, too, you likely need to combine them with the respective spring dependencies and configure a regular spring application.