# Testing non-blocking REST services with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I have a Spring MVC application .
I want to test this controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:backoffice-servlet.xml")
public class TimeControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void should_OK() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/time/2")
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

this is my `backoffice-servlet.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bonanza.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

   
</beans>
```

but when I start the app. I got this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'documentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'documentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'documentRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.bonanza.repositories.documents.DocumentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

the repo:

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentRepository extends JpaRepository<Document, Long> {
...
}
```

Comment: Try changing `<context:component-scan base-package="com.bonanza.*" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.bonanza" />`

Comment: sane result, sir :-(

Comment: Have you tried printing out all the spring loaded beans? Like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602664/print-all-the-spring-beans-that-are-loaded I wonder if backoffice-servlet.xml isn't getting loaded somehow. Is it defo on the cp?

Comment: It is not an SpringBoot application

Comment: Is DocumentRepository annotated with Repository annotation ?

Comment: indeed.It is annotated with Repository annotation

Comment: Could you post code of the repository as well? Or at least its declaration with annotations?

Comment: You probably should add `<jpa:repositories base-package="<<PACKAGE_NAME>>"/>` to the XML config.

Comment: now I have this error: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#117525fe' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#117525fe': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the repository is Spring Data repository, there should be added appropriate initialization in XML config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bonanza.*" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="<<REPOSITORY_PACKAGE_NAME>>"/>
   
</beans>
```

Here is the link to [Spring Data reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring).

If Spring Boot is not used, also it may be needed to add infrastructure JPA classes - dataSource, transactionManager, entityManagerFactory with the reference to entities package. Configuration depends on test environment: is used real / in-memory database or other options. For transaction management there will be also `<tx:annotation-driven />` needed in XML config. Here is link to appropriate chapter of [Spring reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa-dao).

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa#xmlconfig) can be found an example of entity manager factory / transaction manager XML configuration.

Another example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556217/2792888):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        <!-- Set JPA properties -->
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.demo.data" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure the transaction manager bean -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.demo.data" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.svc" />
</beans>
```